# What is the difference between writting class using Code First approch or POCO?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, poco

EF and ORM.

I recently realized that is possible using POCO to have clean classes not plumbed with EF auto generated code.

I saw the new release of EF 4.1 and the use of Code First approach and DbContext.

My questions:

- What is the difference between Code First approach and Poco approach?
- Can we use Code First (DbContext and DbSet) instead of POCO + Repository pattern?

Thanks for your time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're completely different things, and you can use them together.

POCO means that your entity classes are "normal" classes, not dependent on any specific ORM layer.

A `DbContext` is an object that enables you to access the database in an object-oriented way (like `ObjectContext` in earlier versions of EF).

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) for examples.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your comment on this.

Comment: I started to read the article and it states: CODE FIRST Define your model objects by simply writing “plain old classes” with no base classes required
Use a “convention over configuration” approach that enables database persistence without explicitly configuring anything

Comment: So I'm concerning that First Code approach in some how similar to poco? Am I right?

Comment: @GibboK: Code first is the way to map classes to database where you first write classes and generate database from them. Those classes can be persistent ignorant = POCO.

Comment: ok I understand your point.. so where I add the actual code for persistence? Repository? So with EF 4.1 could I avoid using an Repository and using instead DbContext and DbSet? Thanks for your time on this

Comment: @Gibbok, the only code you need to write for persistence is a class that inherits DbContext to define your tables. Just create properties of type `DbSet<YourEntity>` with the same names as your tables, and it should work (convention-based mapping)